# Fetch the first vlaue in a sorted dataframe grouped by id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
ID       geoloc         starttime
1       jjbjbjn         2020-01-01 02:20:12
1       123eh2ue        2020-01-01 02:10:10
1       6tyfgxghsvc     2020-01-02 03:06:12
1       6tyfgxghsv1     2020-01-02 05:06:12
1       6tyfgxghsv5     2020-01-05 05:06:12
1       6tyfgxghsv2     2020-01-05 06:06:12
2       86ghgx          2021-01-12 03:12:35
2       87ghguygg       2021-01-12 03:09:35
2       87ghguygg       2021-01-13 05:17:35
2       87ghguygg       2021-01-13 03:17:35
2       87ghguyg1       2021-01-19 03:17:35
2       87ghguyg6       2021-01-19 05:17:35
```

The resulted dataframe I want is:

```
ID    geoloc        starttime
1    123eh2ue        2020-01-01 02:10:10
1    6tyfgxghsvc     2020-01-02 03:06:12
1    6tyfgxghsv5     2020-01-05 05:06:12
2    87ghguygg       2021-01-12 03:09:35
2    87ghguygg       2021-01-13 03:17:35
2    87ghguyg6       2021-01-19 05:17:35
```

How can I achieve this with efficient way?

Tried with

```
output_df = df.groupby(['ID','starttime']).agg('first')
```

Comment: Use `df.sort_values(by='starttime').drop_duplicates(subset='ID')`

Comment: @jezrael this will give only one entry per ID.Lets say ID 1 has 100 entries: 10 different entry for 10 different date. So for each date I want to fetch the first records sorted by timestamp.So in the output for ID1 there should be total 10 entries. I have changed the example in the question

Comment: So need `df.sort_values(by='starttime').groupby('ID').head(2)` ?

Comment: @jezrael In actual scenario there would be entries for each date for a given month. So head(2) will ignore rest of the values for other dates

Comment: Can you change data sample for see problem why `df.sort_values(by='starttime').groupby('ID').head(2)` failed?

Comment: changed the sample dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expected ouput are unique values per dates, so use [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])

df['new'] = df['starttime'].dt.date

df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','new','starttime']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','new'])
print (df)
    ID       geoloc           starttime         new
1    1     123eh2ue 2020-01-01 02:10:10  2020-01-01
2    1  6tyfgxghsvc 2020-01-02 03:06:12  2020-01-02
4    1  6tyfgxghsv5 2020-01-05 05:06:12  2020-01-05
7    2    87ghguygg 2021-01-12 03:09:35  2021-01-12
9    2    87ghguygg 2021-01-13 03:17:35  2021-01-13
10   2    87ghguyg1 2021-01-19 03:17:35  2021-01-19
```

Last remove `new` column:

```
df = df.drop('new', axis=1)
```

If need unique values per months use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html), but ouput is different:

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])

df['new'] = df['starttime'].dt.to_period('m')

df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','new','starttime']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','new'])
print (df)
   ID     geoloc           starttime      new
1   1   123eh2ue 2020-01-01 02:10:10  2020-01
7   2  87ghguygg 2021-01-12 03:09:35  2021-01
```